# openStdDlg returning null in Chrome

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I have been using `openStdDlg` method for opening a Lookup view in Dynamics CRM. Problem is that this method returns null in Chrome when a user selects a record in the lookup and press OK but works normally in IE. I have Dynamics CRM 2016 On-premise v8.1.0.359.

```
return openStdDlg(oUrl, wndArgs, width, height, true);
```

Any tips / ideas how to get around this problem?

Comment: Try using `openStdWin`, works both on IE and Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dig into the `openStdDlg` function you may find it leveraging `showModalDialog` (not sure it does) which was [removed from Chrome a while back](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Window/showModalDialog).

An alternative unsupported way which should still work is `Mscrm.CrmDialog`. So you can try something like:

```
var dialogWidth = 500;
var dialogHeight = 500;
//replace with your lookup dialog URL
var lookupDialogUrl = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/_controls/lookup/lookupinfo.aspx?AllowFilterOff=0&...";
var callbackRef = function(r){alert(r)};
//instantiate dialog
var dialogWindow = new window.top.Mscrm.CrmDialog(Mscrm.CrmUri.create(lookupDialogUrl), window, dialogWidth, dialogHeight);
//set callback to execute when selection is made and dialog closes
dialogWindow.setCallbackReference(callbackRef);
dialogWindow.show();
```

The above would launch a lookup dialog (once you fill in the rest of the lookup path) and then in your callback you can use the result from the lookup dialog for whatever you need.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. There's a high need to standardized methods that are cross browser compatible and easy to find. I hope somebody at Microsoft listens to that.

Comment: @A.K Totally agree. The method above is unsupported (so you'll want to validate it still works after upgrades), but it's the closest thing we have currently to the UI paradigm CRM uses all over the place of "modal" dialogs.